# Що таке "гойра"?

Tags: значення-слів

У відомій весільній пісні є слова "Гойра вісілє". Також якось я був в Чернівцях, і там є бар, який також називається "Гойра". Також знаю, що в Львові є [студія вишивки](https://hoyra.com.ua/) з такою ж назвою, тобто, мені здається, що це слово є популярним. Але що воно означає?

В СУМі цього слова немає і пошуки в Інтернеті нічого не дали. Я припускаю, що це просто вигук кшталт "Ура" (Ура весілля), але я не впевнений, що це точно так.

Comment: Є ще танець [Ойра](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ойра)

Answer (score 3):

Слово *гойра* походе від  [*hajrá*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hajr%C3%A1#Hungarian), котре має переважно два значеня, в тому числї і для [запозики](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=vYUjAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%B0%22&dq=%22%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%B0%22).

1. Вираз підбадьору, заохоти, пітримки тощо.

   пр. *вперед, (Динаме!)*; *ну*; *мерщій*; *ура* тощо.
2. Кінець або стан такого *(поспіх)*.